# How to see all the threads that are spawned by an android application

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have an android application where I am performing some operations in background threads. For some reason my app becomes extremely slow and unresponsive after being used for few minutes. I am suspecting that it is because of some background thread, so I want to monitor the threads that my app is creating. However, I couldn't find a suitable tool where I can see and monitor those threads. Is there any way I monitor the background threads  at runtime.

Comment: Its unlikely to be due to a background thread-  the entire point of a background thread is that it happens on another timeslice so other threads don't become unresponsive.  Unless you have insane amounts of locking between them, your problem is elsewhere.  I'd profile your app instead and see where your app is spending time.

Comment: It could be due to memory leaks, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DDMS` to monitor the `Threads` at runtime. Look at the `DDMS`  [document](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/ddms.html#running) .

Comment: Try adb commands: adb kill-server and adb start-server, more adb commands details look at [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html?hl=ch-us)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about how can you see threads but you can try following

- Enable Strict mode in developer setting, you will see screen flashing red on heavy operations.
- Add logs to your thread and print progress with time, by this you can know which method is taking time.

More on strict mode here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html

Comment: There's profilers built into android studio, no need to use home rolled inaccurate solutions like logs of time.

Comment: @GabeSechan Can you help me on how to use those profilers

Comment: @Ezio Way past my bedtime.  But start reading up on it at https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/traceview.html   It basically will keep track of how much time you spend in every function of your app, how many times they're all called, how much time is spend in functions called by every function, etc.  Its a valuable tool.  It will degrade performance a bit more while running it, but for this purpose it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the build in tools to profile the app.

See here : https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/traceview.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you can monitor the threads, but you may get the active Thread count of an app.

```
Log.d("ThreadCount : ",""+Thread.activeCount());
```